# HQL/Criteria returns single rows against the expected two

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

This is my query in HQL where I am returning rows based on my clientId but it only returns 1 and the db has 2. Any ideas?

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select e.applicationId, e.serviceId, e.providerId from ClientApplicationServiceProvider e where e.clientId = :clientId").setParameter("clientId", clientId);
```

The same thing in criteria is also returning single row.

```
cr = session.createCriteria(ClientApplicationServiceProvider.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("clientId", clientId));
            ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
            proj.add(Projections.property("applicationId"));
            proj.add(Projections.property("serviceId"));
            proj.add(Projections.property("providerId"));
            cr.setProjection(proj);
```

SQL from a Hibernate log

```
select clientappl0_.application_id as col_0_0_, 
clientappl0_.service_id as col_1_0_, 
clientappl0_.provider_id as col_2_0_ 
from vas_client_application_service_provider clientappl0_ 
where clientappl0_.client_id=?
```

Database:

```
id, clientid, appid, serviceid, provid
'1', 'TERC001', '13', '1001', 'DRT001'
'2', 'TERC002', '12', '1002', 'DRT021'
'3', 'TERC001', '13', '1001', 'DRT013'
```

Comment: Whats the argument and did you check the generated query (show-sql=true)

Comment: clientId = TERC001

Comment: The problem is most likely somewhere else, since I don't see it.  I would enable the sql logging and check the generated query.

Comment: Hibernate: select clientappl0_.application_id as col_0_0_, clientappl0_.service_id as col_1_0_, clientappl0_.provider_id as col_2_0_ from vas_client_application_service_provider clientappl0_ where clientappl0_.client_id=?

Comment: Execute exactly this query on the database with client id 'TERC001'. It does not make sense for me if this returns just 1 row. (Make sure that your database tool has no uncommited changes)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot, the data was only in the csv and was never committed to the db.